STM32CubeProgrammer : Flash Loader cannot be loaded
I’ve developed a custom Flashloader for an STM32 device, and the code compiles without any errors. I then copied the .stldr file into the installation directory of STM32CubeProgrammer. However, when I try to download a binary using the STM32CubeProgrammer, I encounter the following error: "FlashLoader cannot be loaded."
Does anyone have insights on what might be causing this issue or how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Is that the exact error message that you get? Because I've seen a similar error with recent versions of CubeProgrammer, but not quite that. Not sure my workaround will work if it's a different issue.

Yes it is the exact error, can you help me to solve it and thank you in avance

For me the error was like "FlashLoader 0x cannot be loaded". The solution was to go into STM32CubeProgrammer/bin/FlashLoader and copy the file that matched my device ID (e.g. 0x480.stldr) and name it 0x.

I ran into the same problem today, on first connect i got the report "FlashLoader 0x cannot be loaded", and when i tried to reset the Read Out Protection I got the error "Flash Loader cannot be loaded".
The comment of pmacfarlane provided the solution:

... go into STM32CubeProgrammer/bin/FlashLoader and copy the file that matched my device ID (e.g. 0x480.stldr) and name it 0x.

